# How to replace column in list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, replace

I have a list of lists like

```
l1=[[1 2]
    [3 4]
    [5 6]]
```

and another list

```
l2=[[5]
    [3]
    [9]]
```

I want to replace the elements in second column of `l1` with `l2`, so something like

```
l1=[[1 5]
    [3 3]
    [5 9]]
```

I tried doing it like `l1[:,1]=np.reshape(l2,(3))` but it doesn't seem to work and in other ways I just get errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to work"? What happens?

Comment: commas are missed in the list notation

Comment: well nothing happens at all l1 prints the same elements

Comment: commas are not missed it's a list of list

Comment: try enter `l1=[[1 2]
    [3 4]
    [5 6]]` in console and you will see syntax error

Comment: you are mixing up  python lists and numpy arrays string representation

Comment: Try running the code containing the list of lists as you've written in your question. It will throw an error. The syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it. This works for me.

```py
import numpy as np

l1=np.asanyarray([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
l2=np.asanyarray([[5], [3], [9]])

l1[:,1] = l2[:,0]

# output: [[1 5]
#          [3 3]
#          [5 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should just work. Sure something else isn't wrong?

```
import numpy as np

l1 = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
l2 = np.array([[5], [3], [9]])

l1[:,1] = l2.reshape(3)
# Or you can do
l1[:,1] = np.reshape(l2, 3)

print(l1)
```

Outputs:

```
[[1 5]
 [3 3]
 [5 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out(if anyone will need it in future), I flatten the original list then split the list in two lists then add elements at even indices and reshape it, and it seems to work.

```
m1=l1.flatten()
l12=[]
l11=[]
for i in range(0,len(m1)):
   if i % 2==0:
   l12.append(m1[i])
   else:
   l11.append(m1[i])

for x in range(len(l12)):
  l1.insert(2*x+1, l2[x])
print(np.reshape(l12,(3,2)))
```